# Failing cast from Any to Int

Tags: swift

I have the following dictionary of type `[String: Any]` (this is what the log looks like):

```
["name": Cesare de Cal, "last_name": de Cal, "email": hi@cesare.io, "id": 1012058902268810, "first_name": Cesare]
```

I want to get the profile ID "id":

```
if let fbID = fbValues["id"] as? Int {
    print("here should be the fb Id", fbID)
} else {
    print("cast failed") // cast failed
}
```

but this cast fails. Why? I'm assuming "id" (1012058902268810) is a number, right?

Comment: Maybe the `id` value is coming in as a string. None of the other values in your log are properly quoted either, so it's impossible for us to know.

Comment: and yeah that's correct actually, wow I missed that

Comment: @robmayoff that was correct. It was actually a string. Feel free to answer if you'd like

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't even compile...

Comment: @Cristik that was not the definition of a dict, it was just the console output when you `print(dict)`. If I had the definition of a dict I wouldn't be asking this question since I'd already know what type the `id` would be.

Comment: @Cesare for example `po dict["id"]` in the console, or `po type(of: dict["id"]!)`

Comment: I did, it was `Any`, so not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know whether the `id` value is coming in as a `String` or an `Int`, you could try handling both:

```
switch fbValues["id"] {
case nil:
    print("no id given")
case let string as String:
    if let id = Int(string) { print("id = \(id)") }
    else { print("non-numeric id \(string)") }
case let id as Int:
    print("id = \(id)")
default:
    print("what is this I don't even")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

rob already provided you with a possible solution. Just to answer your question about why the cast fails, it fails because of how type casting works in Swift:

From the documentation:

> Type casting is a way to check the type of an instance, or to treat
>   that instance as a different superclass or subclass from somewhere
>   else in its own class hierarchy. (...)
>   A constant or variable of a certain class type may actually
>   refer to an instance of a subclass behind the scenes. Where you
>   believe this is the case, you can try to downcast to the subclass type
>   with a type cast operator (as? or as!). (...)
>   Casting does not actually modify the instance or change its values. The underlying instance remains the same; it is simply treated and accessed as an instance of the type to which it has been cast.

This will work:

```
let something: Any = 1
let number = something as! Int
```

This won't work:

```
let something: Any = "1"
let number = something as! Int
```

This won't work either because Int has no initializer for type Any:

```
let something: Any = "1"
let number = Int(something)
```

But this will work - first you cast to `String` and then you coerce to `Int` (and `Int` has an initializer that accepts `String`)

```
let something: Any = "1"
let string = something as! String
let number = Int(string)!
```

Edit to answer Cesare: You're right. I edited my answer to just provide more info about type casting since you already had your problem solved ;)

And these were just some examples for getting the cast/coercion point across. In a real scenario you shouldn't be forcing unwrapping any of this as John Montgomery pointed out.

Comment: `fbValues["id"] ` may be nil because the key may not exist in the dictionary. You need to handle that. Plus it turns out that was a string not a integer, so the issue wasn't the way I was casting `Any` to `Int`.

Comment: And of course, in real code you shouldn't be using `as!` if you can help it, especially in a situation like this where you can't be certain about the data integrity.